# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre las interfaces Set<> y Map<>?

Tags: java

Quiero saber la diferencia entre usar una lista con la interface Set<> y la interface Map<> cual me resulta mejor para acceder mas fácilmente a los datos?.

Comment: theboshy, bienvenido. Te recomiendo que leas [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ya que tu pregunta es demasiado amplia.

Comment: Estas hablando de colecciones de Java, de https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html y  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html  Te recomiendo ver que coleccion se adapta mejor a tu proyecto o estilo de trabajo :)

Comment: muchas gracias @elporfirio me doy cuenta lo confundido que estaba se lo agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La diferencia es la funcionalidad definida para cada una de estas interfaces:

- [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) es una interfaz que define almacenar objetos en pares de tipo Llave (o Clave) Valor, donde puedes registrar, obtener y remover un elemento a partir de la Llave.

  Ejemplo:

  ```
  //creamos el mapa
  Map<String, Usuario> mapa = new HashMap<>();
  //agregamos elementos al mapa
  mapa.put("Luiggi Mendoza J", new Usuario(227, "Luiggi Mendoza J", 10.4k));
  mapa.put("theboshy", new Usuario(9206, "theboshy", 1));
  System.out.println(mapa.get("theboshy")); //imprime datos de usuario
  System.out.println(mapa.get("elporfirio")); //imprime nulo
  //recorrer todas las entradas llave-valor del mapa
  //e imprimir la llave y el valor correspondiente
  for (Map.Entry<String, Usuario> entry : mapa.entrySet()) {
      System.out.printf(
          "Llave: %s. Valor: %s\n",
          entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
  }
  ```

  Solo puede existir 1 Valor asociado a una Llave. Esto no significa que pueda haber 1 Valor asociado a múltiples Llaves. Ejemplo:

  ```
  Map<String, String> mapa = new HashMap<>();
  mapa.put("saludo", "hola mundo");
  System.out.println(mapa.get("saludo")); //imprime 'hola mundo'
  String valor = "aloha!";
  //reemplazamos el valor de la llave "saludo"
  mapa.put("saludo", valor);
  System.out.println(mapa.get("saludo")); //imprime 'aloha!'
  //asignamos el mismo valor a una nueva llave
  mapa.put("saludo efusivo", valor);
  System.out.println(mapa.get("saludo"));
  System.out.println(mapa.get("saludo efusivo"));
  //ambas sentencias imprimieros 'aloha!'
  ```
- [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) es una interfaz que define almacenar objetos como si fuese un conjunto matemático. Esto permite que se puedan registrar y remover elementos de este conjunto, pero **no permite** obtenerlos uno por uno. `Set` se usa principalmente para verificar que no hayan objetos repetidos en una colección.

  Ejemplo:

  ```
  Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
  //agregamos elementos
  set.add(10);
  set.add(5);
  set.add(8);
  //podemos remover elementos
  set.remove(10);
  //pero no podemos obtener elementos, no existe un método `get`
  //lo que si, existe un método `contains` que permite verificar
  //si un elemento existe en el set
  if (set.contains(5)) {
      System.out.println("5 existe");
  }
  //sin embargo, se pueden recorrer todos los elementos de un set
  for (Integer elem : set) {
      System.out.println(elem);
  }
  ```

  Cabe resaltar que un `Set` puede ser visto simplemente como un `Map<Object, Boolean>`, donde los objetos a insertar en el `Set` son las llaves del `Map`. Esto se puede comprobar mediante el uso del método [`Collections#newSetFromMap(Map<E, Boolean>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap-java.util.Map-).

Comment: muchas gracias amigo exactamente lo que necesitaba :)